# Selection Sort through malloc function

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n,min,j;
    int *array; 
    printf("The no of elements >> ");
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    printf("Making array\n" );
    array = (int *)malloc (sizeof(int) * n);
    printf("array made!\n");

    //INPUT NUMBERS
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf(">>Enter the element %d\n" , i+1);
            scanf("%d\n", &array[i]);
        }

    //SORT THE ARRAY
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            min = array[0];
            for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
            {
                if (array[i] > array[j])
                    min = array[j];
            }
            if (min != array[i])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = array[i];
                array[i]= min;
                array[j]=temp;
            }
        }

    //PRINTING ARRAY
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf("-- %d --\n" , array[i]);
        };
}
```

I have this particular code for SelectionSort in c using Malloc for arrays. However, it is going through intake of input 2 times after "the no of elements>>" and won't sort either.
If I go on with the way it is, it is giving me an unsorted array in the following way

```
The no of elements >> 5
4
Making array
array made!
>>Enter the element 1
5
>>Enter the element 2
2
>>Enter the element 3
1
>>Enter the element 4
7
>>Enter the element 5
8
-- 7 --
-- 1 --
-- 1 --
-- 2 --
-- 1 --
```

I have read a few other posts and corrected my code , but this still won't work. 
Can't figure out why.

**Edit 1**  The problem for double input did resolve by making a few changes to code.

```
int main()
{   int i,n,min,j;
    int *array; 
    printf("The no of elements >> ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    array = (int *)malloc (sizeof(int) * n);

    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf(">>Enter the element %d\n" , i+1);
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        }

    //SORT THE ARRAY
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            min = array[i];
            for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
            {
                if (array[i] > array[j])
                    min = array[j];
            }
            if (min != array[i])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = array[i];
                array[i]= min;
                array[j]=temp;
            }
        }

    //PRINTING ARRAY
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf("-- %d --\n" , array[i]);
        };
}
```

however , now the input is still not correct

```
The no of elements >> 5
Making array
array made!
>>Enter the element 1
5
>>Enter the element 2
4
>>Enter the element 3
6
>>Enter the element 4
9
>>Enter the element 5
2
-- 9 --
-- 2 --
-- 2 --
-- 2 --
-- 2 --
```

**Edit 2**
After a few corrections, and still few errors away from the final code, am at

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n,min,j;
    int *array; 
    printf("The no of elements >> ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Making array\n" );
    array = (int *)malloc (sizeof(int) * n);
    printf("array made!\n");

    //INPUT NUMBERS
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf(">>Enter the element %d\n" , i+1);
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        }

    //SORT THE ARRAY
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for ( j = i+1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] < array[i])
                    min = j;
            }
            if (min != i)
            {
                int temp;
                temp = array[i];
                array[i]= array[min];
                array[min]=temp;
            }
        }

    //PRINTING ARRAY
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf("-- %d --\n" , array[i]);
        };
}
```

which is leading to a somewhat sorted , still incorrect, array

```
The no of elements >> 5
Making array
array made!
>>Enter the element 1
4
>>Enter the element 2
5
>>Enter the element 3
2
>>Enter the element 4
1
>>Enter the element 5
7
-- 1 --
-- 4 --
-- 2 --
-- 5 --
-- 7 --
```

**Edit 3 :final code**
I edited the code several times for hit and trial. I have finally found this code as working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n,min,j;
    int *array; 
    printf("The no of elements >> ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Making array\n" );
    array = (int *)malloc (sizeof(int) * n);
    printf("array made!\n");

    //INPUT NUMBERS
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf(">>Enter the element %d\n" , i+1);
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        }

    //SORT THE ARRAY
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            min = i;
            for ( j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
            {
                if (array[j] < array[min])
                    min = j;
            }
            if (min != i)
            {
                int temp;
                temp = array[i];
                array[i]= array[min];
                array[min]=temp;
            }
        }

    //PRINTING ARRAY
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf("-- %d --\n" , array[i]);
        };
}
```

**However I will still be interested to know why ++i /++j make no difference when compared to i++/j++ respectively.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems remaining with your code after edit 1.

The `j` inside your middle loop is shadowing the `j` declared at the top of the function. So while that inner for loop may find the correct index to swap with, that information is lost after the inner loop ends.

Change:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
```

to:

```
for (j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
```

Second, you shouldn't be keeping track of the value of the minimum element. Instead, you should track its index. `j` is always equal to `n` after the inner loop, so your code is going to assign the minimum element to every element of the array.

Change:

```
min = array[i];
// ...
    min = array[j];
// ...
if (min != array[i])
// ...
    array[i]=min;
    array[j]=temp;
```

to:

```
min = i;
// ...
    min = j;
// ...
if (min != i)
// ...
    array[i]=array[min];
    array[min]=temp;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help. It has corrected the code to a great extent and led me to Edit 2.
However, I couldn't understand why should we keep track of the index and not element itself, completely.

Comment: If you don't keep track of the index, you don't know which position to swap `array[i]` with. All you'd know is that some position has a value of `min`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

NOT:

```
scanf("%d\n",&n);
```

**Edit**:

Inside the outer for loop, it should be `min = array[i];`.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help.
And I don't think Writing "min" instead of "array[i]" is going to lead to a sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `min = array[i];` instead of`min = array[0];`

Comment: yeah, corrected that. I realised it was again and again comparing to 0th index which led to errors

Answer (score 0):

In, scanf("%d\n",&n);
'\n' tells scanf to read but not save. So it waits for a non-white space character to be read.